# R shiny help! Render tabsetPanel under dashboard-tabItem

Tags: r, shiny, server, tabs, dashboard

I am new to R shiny, and I want to create a user interface using dashboard. The UI I got when running the code on my company's R server, 'RStudio Workbench 2022.02.0 Build 443.pro2' version, I got the results as [picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnsoP.png) shows. I want my "Data1", "Data2", and "Data3" to be tabs, like [picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECSRo.png) shows. I can get what I want when I run the code on local R studio.

Can someone help me to see if there is a problem with my code, or if it is an issue with my company's server?

here is my code of UI:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


header<-dashboardHeader(title='Test', color = "darkblue", inverted = TRUE)

sidebar<-dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
  menuItem(tabName = 'application', text = 'Go/No Go', icon=icon("calculator")),
  menuItem(tabName = 'example', text = 'Example',icon=icon("book")),
  menuItem(tabName = 'readme', text = 'Read me',icon = icon("glasses")),
  menuItem(tabName = 'theory', text = 'Theory',icon = icon("percent"))
  
))


body<-  dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
           tabItem(tabName = "application",
                   tabsetPanel(tabPanel("Data1"),
                   tabPanel("Data2"),
                   tabPanel("Data3")))
  ))

#Dashboard page
ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your `dashboardHeader` code it seem reference to param that not available within the function.

```r
# Removed color & inverted
header <- dashboardHeader(title='Test')
```

##### Result

[image: Shiny app with tabset]

Comment: I tried this before, but it doesn't work. I can get the same result as yours on my local Rstudio, but not on my company's server.